# Why is one of my variables returning undefined in a switch and case?

Tags: switch-statement, undefined

I'm trying to create a currency converter from USD to whatever other currency. I have simplified the code to the part I am having issues with.

```
const toCurrency = document.getElementById("toCurrency");
const returnValue = document.getElementById("returnValue");
let usdInput = document.getElementById("inputValue");


let submit = {
    conversionSubmit: () => { 
        conversion.conversion()
    }
}


let conversion = {
    conversion: () => {
        switch(toCurrency.value) {
            case USD: returnValue.innerText = usdInput.value; 
            return usdInput.value; 
        }
    }
    
};
```

The issue here is that my usdInput.value returns undefined when I run the function even though when I see what the variable is through the console, it is perfectly defined.
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `case "USD"`?

Comment: ^^^ What they said. Add a default case to the end of your switch so you know when none of your checks passed.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Happy New Years